# How can I make 'logout' really work for vnc session

Tags: vnc

Ubuntu 11.04

vncserver 4.1.1+xorg4.3.0-37ubuntu2

My .vnc/xstartup ends with `gnome-session`.

When I select 'logout' from the window on the upper right, gnome deletes all its bits, from the screen, but the session remains in existence. I wish that vncserver would get -kill-ed. Is there a way to arrange this?

Comment: Shouldn't it end with 'gnome-session &' ?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: I've lost interest. Go ahead and close it.

Comment: flagged for closing per OP